# Point is randomly selected from area, find the mean of abscissa.

Tags: probability, random-variables

My question goes like this:

> A point is randomly selected from the yellow area, which is enclosed by the parabola $y = x^2$ and straight lines $y = 0, x = 0.97$, and $x = 2.78$. **Find the mean of abscissa of this point.**

This is the area where the point should be found:

[image]

But I have no idea how should I find the mean of abscissa.

Any help appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1=.97$ and let $x_2=2.78$. Let
$$
R=\{(x,y)\colon x_1<x<x_2,\ 0<y<x^2\}.
$$
You are asking for the expectation of $X$ when $(X,Y)$ are drawn from the uniform distribution in $R$. Since
$$
\mathbb EX=\frac{\int_{R}x\ dx\ dy}{\int_R dx\ dy},
$$
we obtain the answer by performing the appropriate two integrals.
More explicitly,
$$
\int_R dx\ dy=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x^2\ dx=\frac{x_2^3-x_1^3}{3},
$$
and
$$
\int_R x\ dx\ dy=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x^3\ dx=\frac{x_2^4-x_1^4}{4}.
$$
You can do the rest...